# Embed a Gmap in a Views Slideshow

Tags: views, media, google-maps, javascript

I have been trying to embed a location map in a [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow). The slideshow is made with the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module and it already contains an embedded youtube video and photos whose view is controlled through a thumbnail pager at the bottom of the slideshow. I want to be able to add a location map as the first slide of my slideshow. Is this possible? Could you please provide me with some information on this topic?

Comment: You want only the map and nothing else on the 1st slide?

Comment: Can you give more information on how you are making a slideshow with the media module?

Comment: Thank you for the reply,

yes, I only want the map and nothing else on the 1st slide.

The slideshow is this one: http://www.leorealestate.gr/en/property/sa7

I want to embed the gmap inside the slideshow, exactly like I did for the youtube video.

Comment: Any ideas? Anyone? Something? Please...